# Scrollbar can't scroll to end of container

Tags: jquery, html, css

currently i have many row of product, but i found it cannot let me to scroll until the end of the container as picture shown below, whats wrong there? and is it impossible no need to set a max-height there? because i will add in more Row in future.

```
<div class="tab-content" id="fe-scrollable">
  <div>CONTENT HERE</div>
  <div>CONTENT HERE</div>
  <div>CONTENT HERE</div>
  <div>CONTENT HERE</div>
</div>

.tab-content {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 1180px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the "tab-9" "tab-10" stuff is hiding it?

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be helpful if you could let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have another DIV or container that is being positioned over the top of your scrollbar content. You might have to look into structuring your page a bit differently so that either the tabs sit behind your scrollable content or, even better, so that the scrollable content sits above the tab content.

It's hard to tell how exactly you've structured your code but maybe you do do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="scrollable-content">
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div>Tab 1</div>
        <div>Tab 2</div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: yup, the structure is like this, just the scrollable-content div can't scroll to the end of the container,the row show half when i scroll to end

Comment: It's still hard to tell how you've done this without more code but you might need to change some CSS to and make the tab content position: relative.

Another hacky way to do it would be to just shorten the height of the scrollable content by the height of the tab content. height: calc(100% - 50px) where 50px is the height of the tab-content. That's pretty hacky though..